# Use many-to-many built in Entity Framework or create manually another entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following relationships: [image]

My question here is: do I use the built in many-to-many in Entity Framework so internally EF creates a table name `ProductCategory`, or do I manually create the table and manually set the relation 1-Many and 1-Many; in the `ProductCategory` table, I only need the foreign keys of the tables nothing else, which approach is recommended the built in or doing it manually? And why?

> EDIT: As someone mention I decided to create my own table to have a
>   better control over it and be able to modify it,my table now has the
>   following attributes:
>
> ```
> public class ProductCategory : IProductCategory {
>     public int ProductCategoryId { set; get; }
>     [ForeignKey("Category")]
>     [Column(Order = 1)]
>     public int CategoryId { set; get; }
>     [ForeignKey("Product")]
>     [Column(Order = 2)]
>     public int ProductId { set; get; }
>     public virtual Product Product { set; get; }
>   public virtual Category Category { set; get; }
> }
> ```

Comment: At the moment, your model is very basic and there are no pros to doing it manually. However, if you build it manually now you will save yourself the hassle in the future if you ever need to add more columns in the bridge table or want a manage section to add products to a category. It is so much easier to add/delete from a bridge table then it is to modify full lists. You won't be able to access the bridge with entity framework if it is created automatically.

Comment: @MIKE thanks you very much, unfortunately you didn't post an answer just a comment so I'm unable to choose you as the right answer

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess if you don't need anything but the keys in the ProductCategory, you can use the built-in way.
If you need some other information stored with the ProductCategory, maybe you need versioning or some advanced features, you might go with a custom join entity.

Also see these answers:

[Adding 0..1 relation in EF code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370899/adding-0-1-relation-in-ef-code-first/43371838#43371838)

[EF 1 to 1..* relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44518699/ef-1-to-1-relationship/44519550#44519550)